# The argument type 'List<Datum>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Datum>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Flutter environment: sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

Error:

```
I/flutter (28168): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'map'.
I/flutter (28168): Receiver: ""
I/flutter (28168): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Datum)
E/flutter (28168): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'map'.
E/flutter (28168): Receiver: ""
E/flutter (28168): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Datum)
```

I have tried the below solution

```
factory AddressGetResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => AddressGetResponse(
    status: json["status"],
    message: json["message"],
    data: json["data"] == null ? null :List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );
```

but got the above Error:

> The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

Comment: are you sure? your json['data'] is List as your console is mentioning that it is String and String don't have method map.

Answer (score 1):

The mode you created `AddressGetResponse`, it is something like `List<Datum> data`. Means data doesn't accept the null value.

On null cases, you are doing

```dart
data: json["data"] == null ? null :.....
```

Means you are trying to assign null value on non-nullable filed. And null—safety raise the error.

You can make the data filed nullable`

```dart
class AddressGetResponse{
  final List<Datum>? data;
  ....
```

Or provide empty list on null case.

```dart
 data: json["data"] == null ? []:List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
```

More about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

use this in your model

```
data: json["data"]==null?[]:List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

`data: (json["data"] == null ? null :List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))))!,`

rap the data in () and add ! to it.